# c++ only: unary minus for 0x80000000

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer, unary-operator

This question is supposedly for language-lawyers.

Suppose that signed and unsigned int are both 32 bits wide. As stated in the n3337.pdf draft, 5.3.1.8,

`(-(0x80000000u)) = 0x100000000u-0x80000000u = 0x80000000u`

But I can not find the answer to the question: what will be unary minus for **signed** 0x80000000? Is it UB, implementation defined, or ... ?

**The question is mostly about run-time calculation.**

Say

```
   signed int my_minus(signed int i) { return -i;}
   ....
   int main() {
       signed int a = -0x7FFFFFFF; // a looks like 0x80000001
       signed int b = a - 1;       // b looks like 0x80000000
       std::cout << my_minus(b);
       ....
   }
```

Still, your comments on other 2 cases are welcome:

- Compile-time constant folding, say, `-(INT_MIN)`
- Compile-time calculation of `constexpr` (if there is a difference with compile-time constant folding).

---

( Please look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123713/is-splitting-a-question-a-good-practice before voting for duplicate. )

Comment: It's helpful to link to the previous question when posting further questions on the same topic: [unary minus for 0x80000000 (signed and unsigned)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474699/unary-minus-for-0x80000000-signed-and-unsigned)

Comment: @GregHewgill There is a link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123713/is-splitting-a-question-a-good-practice (that is, is splitting a question a good practice?) and it contains link to my previous question.

Answer (score 4):

Signed integer overflow is always undefined, as far as I know.  From the C++ spec section **5 Expressions**, paragraph 4:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined. [*Note:* most existing implementations of C++ ignore integer overflows. Treatment of division by zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all floating point exceptions vary among machines, and is usually adjustable by a library function. *—endnote*]

Answer (score 3):

Signed integral types obey the rules of mathematical integers without added computer bullshit. So `-std::numeric_limits< signed_type >::min()` is going to be undefined behavior, if the given type cannot represent the resulting number.

In a `constexpr`, the implementation is *required* to reject that expression, as anything causing undefined behavior renders a constant expression invalid, as a diagnosable rule. In this case the rule is one of the forbidden items in §5.19,

> — a result that is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type;

In constant folding, the compiler is most likely to insert the overflowed value.